# WPF ListView Sorting loses column data in the last row

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting

I am facing a strange behaviour while sorting the WPF ListView ColHeader !!
I have a listview binded to a datatable.
Cols have cell templates.

In one of the cell template [salary column], I have multibinding in xaml.
When this listview is loaded with data, everything is working fine.

And I changed the numeric value of salary columns such as 1,4,3,5,2 in each row respectively.

ie, in the first row, salary col is 1, 
second row, salary col is 4, third row salary col is 3, etc.

when i clicked on the salary header column for sorting, the listview is sorting but the last typed value in the salary text box [ie, 2 in here case] disappears !!!

```
ICollectionView myview = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);

if (myview != null)
{                
   myview.SortDescriptions.Clear();
   SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("Salary", direction);
   myview.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
   myview.Refresh();
}
```

When i checked the myview after sort desc is added, the Salary value in the last row disappears !! Is there anything wrong in it ???

Answer (score 0):

I can speculate what is happening based on your description but showing the xaml of the datatable would be useful. Bindings for the Text property of a TextBox, by default, does not commit the value until it loses focus. Change the UpdateSourceTrigger of your binding to PropertyChanged:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This will commit the value on every key press. Can't be sure if this is your problem without seeing the code.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: I solved the issue. It was the mistake of some code written in text box lost focus event. I fixed it. Thanks for the help.